# Permissible to light one Yom Tov candle from another?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, candle-lighting

In a two-day Yom Tov in the diaspora, is it permissible to light two Yom Tov candles on Yom Tov Rishon, one of which is a 24-hour candle, and then, on Yom Tov Sheini, to light two Yom Tov candles for Yom Tov Sheini from that 24-hour candle that was lit for Yom Tov Rishon?  Similarly, is it permissible to light Yom Tov candles from someone else's Yom Tov candles on Yom Tov?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This is questionable altogether since we have electricity today,but that's a whole other discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is prohibited to light a regular candle from the Shabbos/Yom Tov candles, it is permitted to light a נר של מצוה. However, one must be careful to only light directly from the Shabbos/Yom Tov candles to each other; lighting a match or splint to carry over the flame is prohibited (as this doesn't constitute נר של מצוה). (SHU"A)

Comment: Where in SHU"A does it say this

Comment: A quick search on Sefaria indicates that the only time the concept of נר של מצוה appears in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim is in 674:2, יש מי שאומר שנר של בית הכנסת ושל שבת ושל חנוכה כולם של מצוה הם ומותר להדליק זה מזה. "There are those who say" that one can light from a Menorah to Shabbos candles or vice versa. If this is indeed what you're referring to, can you infer that *everyone* agrees for the case at hand?

Comment: chortkov2, thanks.  but would it be permitted to light the 2nd candle from the Shabbos/Yom Tov candle, even though the mitzvah has already been done by lighting the first candle?